# Receiver for connection events doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I want to listen to connection changes and tried it as follows:

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- ....... -->

<receiver
        android:name="<packagename>.ConnectionReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Class

```
public class ConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "ConnectionReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Connection changed");

        }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to get called when I put my WiFi conection on and off.

What's the problem here, did I miss something?

Comment: What is that action? Try using android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE action

Comment: Thanks, your are right. But unfortunately, the receiver above was only called one single time although I put WiFi on and off for about 15 times.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

In your AndroidManifest.xml under "manifest"

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml under "application"

```
<receiver android:name="com.blackboard.androidtest.receiver.ConnectionChangeReceiver"           android:label="NetworkConnection">  
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
</intent-filter>      
</receiver>
```

The Receiver class:

```
    public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        NetworkInfo mobNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (activeNetInfo != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Active Network Type : " + activeNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (mobNetInfo != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Mobile Network Type : " + mobNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I can't see the difference here. Isn't this the same I did? My problem is that the onReceive method only get called once, I think your Receiver class (which is definitely better than mine ;) ) cannot fix this. The problem happens **before**

Comment: Hi ceran, android throws a broadcast when internet connection drops or changes status. You just need to catch that broadcast, so you don't need to check everytime.

Comment: hi lars, thanks. This is exactly what I want to do and I think my approach should do this, but it only receives the broadcast once when I change my Wi-Fi connection on and off several times.

Comment: Hi ceran, take a good look at this page: http://thiranjith.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/how-to-monitor-network-connectivity-in-android/ especially register the BroadcastReceiver within the application.

Comment: I already know this page, but the author registers the Receiver in an **activity**, but I do not need any gui-components.